# Message "Notice: Undefined index: ..."

Tags: php, html, mysql

I know this question is asked too many times. And I try to solve my error through those post, but they are not working for me.

Here I am trying to store a username and password using HTML and PHP code on MySQL database. I am also using XAMPP.

My browser shows me an error like this:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\YC\conect.php on line 7

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\YC\conect.php on line 9
Username should not be empty
```

The HTML code is below here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Form site</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form align="center" method="post" action="conect.php">
            Username : <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
            Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And my PHP code in `conect.php`:

```
<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";
    $dbname = "youtube";

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    $username = $_POST['username'];

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    if (empty($username))
    {
        echo "Username should not be empty";
        die();
    }

    if (empty($password))
    {
        echo "Password should not be empty";
        die();
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, password) values ('$username',
           '$password')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    }
    else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

It was my first coding to connect MySQL database using PHP code.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You have to check if the user had entered the username using the isset() or you can add a required attribute in the input tag(which will provide client side validation)

Comment: Below answer contain isset() and I try that but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following format. This might help you.

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username');
        $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');

        if (isset($username) && !empty($username))
        {
            if (isset($password) && !empty($password))
            {
                $host = "localhost";
                $dbusername = "root";
                $dbpassword = "";
                $dbname = "youtube";

                // Create connection
                $conn = new mysqli($host, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);

                // Check connection
                if (mysqli_connect_error())
                {
                    die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' .
                        mysqli_connect_error());
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO account (username, password) values ('$username','$password')";

                    if ($conn->query($sql))
                    {
                        echo "New record created successfully";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Password should not be empty";
                die();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Username should not be empty";
            die();
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Sorry but it does not show me a message like "New record created successfully" and when I check my database, no data has been inserted.

Comment: try using mysqli_query, i updated it, and is there any error showing?

Comment: Sorry but it does not seen to be help full again.

Comment: Problem not solve yet. I think echo "New record created successfully"; is not executing.

Comment: does it insert a data? try to see in the network tab under inspect element the header response, right click the page and select inspect element, select network tab, choose the php file and see the response

Comment: On Response tab It say, "This request data has no response data available"

Comment: try to add this var_dump($_POST); after the condition $_SERVER['Request_Method']) { var_dump($_POST); if it has some value.

Comment: the code works for me, it tested it. i created a simple html and a php file. Are you are using ajax?

Comment: Can you tell me please where to add $_SERVER['Request_Method']) { var_dump($_POST);

Comment: <?php

see the above code,  and look for this line if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]=="POST")
{           var_dump($_POST); //this is where you add the var_dump before $username
$username = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'username');
$password = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'password');

Comment: I add this code but not working. And one more thing, on bottom I add print_r($_POST). And it gives me Array()

Comment: if it give an empty array mean no data submitted in post, i tried to make this. see this http://boi.unaux.com/

Comment: Sorry, I found that problem is in my database table. When I delete and recreate it then it work for me.

Answer (score -1):

Print `$_post` and check the username index is available in this `$_post`:

```
print_r($_POST)
```

Comment: I apply your code at the bottom then I get Array(). What does this means?

Comment: $_POST is an array, it's include all post data as array key and value

Comment: Post value is not available

Comment: Do you have any solution for that.

Comment: `$_post` or `$_POST`? Is it two different things? Is it case sensitive or not?